# Editing Tex documents in Drive

Tags: installing

I have a simple question. Imagine I have some .tex document in a folder of my Drive account, probably making some reference to pictures etc. in the same folder. I would like to somehow work in the Drive folder as if it was a folder in my computer: to open the document, to edit it, to compile it, and that the compiled pdf was saved in the same Drive folder. Is there an easy way to do it? And in this case, would it be as confortable as the standard Latex editing? Otherwise it would be easier to download the folder, work with the document and uploading it again.

Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: To use your Drive folders as local folders you need to install the Drive local client.  This is not really a TeX question.  See http://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything has worked perfectly. You are right, it was not really a Latex question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download Google Drive to your computer instead of working from Drive on your web browser. Same thing for DropBox.